# How to modify the scope field of a Request object in Starlette/FastAPI for unit testing

Tags: python, pytest, aws-api-gateway, fastapi, starlette

Let's say I have a FastAPI route with a basic get request that looks something like:

```py
@router.get("/reports")
async def get_reports(request: Request) -> Dict:
    return
```

and I want to test it using:

```py
def test_method_can_access_request_fields():
    client = TestClient()
    response = client.get("/")
```

Now, if you examine the `request` variable in the route, you'll see a `starlette.requests.request` object. This object has a Dict field, `request.scope`.

We're using Mangum to serve the app as a Lambda on AWS, and our real application is able to receive a field called `aws.event` into this object ([docs](https://mangum.io/adapter/)). I'm trying to figure out how to write a test for the endpoint.

What I think I want to do is to somehow modify the incoming `request.scope` Dictionary to include this custom `aws.event` field using the TestClient.

Is there a way to pass something into the test configuration that will propagate a custom field into the `Request` object?

Answer (score 0):

First, in order to make sure we do not override current scope:

```py
def _update_scope(self, scope1, scope2):
    scope1.update(scope2)
    return scope1
```

Then, create a method that would mock Starlette's request, adding your desired scope:

```py
def mock_request(self, new_scope):
    return lambda scope, send, receive: Request(self._update_scope(scope, new_scope), send, receive)
```

then patch `starlette.routing.Request`:

```py
mock.patch("starlette.routing.Request", mock_request())
```

voila.

Comment: I created a dependency for getting the aws.event from the request and override the dependency for testing

Comment: can I get a feedback on the downvote please?